# Is there an inverse function for the method quantile.survfit in the survival package?

Tags: r, survival

Using a survfit object, I can extract quantiles like this:

```
library('survival')
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = aml) 
quantile(fit)[[1]]
#25 50 75 
#12 27 43
```

Is there a function to perform the inverse? Pass a vector of quantiles, and return the probabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct the estimated survival function with `stepfun`:

```
survfun <- stepfun(fit$time, c(1, fit$surv))
```

Then `survfun` is a function which returns the survival probabilities.

Another way is to use the `times` argument in `summary`:

```
summary(fit, times = c(1, 2, 3))
```

This should give the same as `survfun(c(1,2,3))`.